# Finding values with fewer repititions in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with multiple columns, but the two I care about we can call Alpha and Beta.  There's also a third, Gamma, which is a comparison between Alpha and Beta.  We'll simplify it and say Gamma is the difference between Alpha and Beta, so I have something like this:

```
Alpha  Beta  Gamma
-----  ----  -----
1       A     (some answer)
1       B     (some answer)
1       C     (some answer)
2       A     (some answer)
2       B     (some answer)
2       C     (some answer)
3       A     (some answer)
3       B     (some answer)
3       C     (some answer)
4       A     (some answer)
4       B     (some answer)
4       C     (some answer)
```

At this point the contents are Gamma are not important.

So let's say I end up with a new value in Beta, 'D.'  I have 1D and 3D, but not 2D and 4D.

Can I find, in Sqlite, with a query, which Alpha values do not yet have a corresponding D value?  For instance, in this table:

```
Alpha  Beta  Gamma
-----  ----  -----
1       A     (some answer)
1       B     (some answer)
1       C     (some answer)
1       D     (some answer)
2       A     (some answer)
2       B     (some answer)
2       C     (some answer)
3       A     (some answer)
3       B     (some answer)
3       C     (some answer)
3       D     (some answer)
4       A     (some answer)
4       B     (some answer)
4       C     (some answer)
```

Since I need every Alpha value to have a corresponding Beta value, this seems to be what I need to do:

1. Get a list of values not present for every value in Alpha (In other words, in this case, that would be just D.
2. Get a list of every value in Alpha that does not have a corresponding value in D.

Ultimately, I need to fill the table out so every Alpha value has a matching Beta value for every dinstinct value in Beta.

(**NOTE**: The part after the 2nd table has been changed to provide a list of specific steps I think I need to do.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do:

1) For answer to Question (a):

```
Select beta from test 
  GROUP BY beta
  having count(alpha) < (select count(distinct alpha) from test);
```

2) Question (b):

```
Select alpha from test 
  GROUP BY alpha
  having count(beta) < (select count(distinct beta) from test);
```

Tried with the following as input:

```
Create table test (alpha int, beta varchar(2));

insert into test values (1, "A");
insert into test values (1, "B");
insert into test values (1, "C");
insert into test values (1, "D");
insert into test values (2, "A");
insert into test values (2, "B");
insert into test values (2, "C");
insert into test values (3, "A");
insert into test values (3, "B");
insert into test values (3, "C");
insert into test values (3, "D");
insert into test values (4, "A");                                           
insert into test values (4, "B");                                           
insert into test values (4, "C");
```

Comment: Thank you - this just made me realize I phrased the question wrong - since I need to find out what value in Beta is not used for every one in Alpha.

Comment: On looking at this, in the 2nd line, would you mean "where Beta NOT IN (1,4)?"

Answer (score 0):

Count how many Betas there are for each Alpha:

```
SELECT Alpha, COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Alpha;
```

Then take the maximum value, and retrieve all smaller counts:

```
WITH Counts(Alpha, Count) AS (
  SELECT Alpha, COUNT(*)
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY Alpha
)
SELECT Alpha
FROM Counts
WHERE Count < (SELECT MAX(Count)
               FROM Counts);
```

Comment: I was thinking along similar lines, but was also wondering if this was a "long winded" way to do it.